# DIV with center div and right div inside

Tags: html, css

StackOverflow.
I would like to make html and css layout like this:

[image: css layout image]
I made a mistype, *container is the same **height** as logo.*

I've tried many variants from the internet and stackoverflow, but none of them fit my needs.

What i stopped at:

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="fs-login">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Вход</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Регистрация</a>
    </div>
    <div class="fs-logo">
        <img src="siteimg/eremademo.png"/>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    position:relative;
}
.fs-logo {
    text-align:center;
}
.fs-login {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

what i see:

[image: what i see]

So *buttons are not aligned vertically.*

And also I'm *not glad*, that in HTML *"buttons" code is placed before "logo"* code. It's not logically right, can I avoid this?

I've struggling over that for about 5 hours. Would be glad for any help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `top: 50%`, combined with a `transform: translateY(-50%)` on your `.fs-login` container:

```css
header {
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    position:relative;
}
.fs-logo {
    text-align:center;
}
.fs-login {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="fs-login">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Вход</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Регистрация</a>
    </div>
    <div class="fs-logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x180"/>
    </div>
</header>
```

Side note: `-webkit-` is here for Safari, is you don't use Autoprefixer.

Comment: You're welcome! Keep this trick in mind, it allows you to vertically center anything, anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYdbMN) using floats:

```
header {
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.fs-logo {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align:center;
}
.fs-login {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work :( login div is at the top of logo, that isn't what desired.